# Checkmark appears in a wrong position in profile pictures

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture

The following screenshot is from gaming site, but the bug appears on all sites.

> [image]

You see the checkmark appearing next to Facebook. The profile picture is **not** from Facebook but is an Uploaded picture.

The checkmark is supposed to appear next to "Uploaded picture" text. Right?

This seems to be a minor bug that I found today.

Comment: Any explication for this the downvote? It's clear that this is a bug...